# Use of demeanor with plural subject

Tags: word-usage

Consider the following sentence.

> I was studying the faces and demeanors of the people in the hall.

As the subject is plural, the author naturally used *demeanors*. However, I believe it should be *demeanor*, but I can't actually explain why (or find anything to support my belief).

Can anyone enlighten me on that?

Comment: It wasn't that hard to find, but many dictionaries are mute on the point. [plural of demeanor](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/demeanor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demeanor) lists the word *demeanour* as both countable and uncountable - meaning that both *demeanour* and *demeanours* are acceptable.

Comment: Please don't answer Google-this-for-me questions on ELU.